# Web application upgrade to 4.0 .Net Framework issue

Tags: asp.net, strongly-typed-dataset, connection-timeout

We recently upgraded one of our web applications from 2.0 .net Framework to 4.0 (VS 2010) using the migration wizard. The application worked fine in the lower environments when single user tested it. But after deploying it to production, when a few users (about 20+) hit the application, we saw a flood of errors with the following error message:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached. StackTrace=
>   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()

Note that this application heavily uses typed dataset and I have searched the code for any connection objects explicitly opened (not going through typed dataset) and have not found any.

Its unclear why it errors out after switching to 4.0 framework. We rolled back to 2.0 Framework and things calmed down and all timeout errors disappeared.

Unable to reproduce it in the lower envrionment using `soapUI` and `LoadRunner`.

Any idea what could be different in 4.0 compared to 2.0 internally and also any pointers on how to debug/troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Sounds like you are not disposing SQL connections properly in the request lifetime. Not possible to say why and where without careful audit of your database layer code.

Comment: The code has not changed with the upgrade. The same code works fine with 2.0 framework. What stumps me is why it won't work with 4.0 framework. I believe, with typed datasets, the connections are made behind the scenes and should be disposed when done executing the command.

Comment: "the connections are made behind the scenes " - sure you *can* do it this way, but I'd recommend you control the connections explicitly in code in an application of any size or complexity.  This doesn't really bear on your question, although it would maybe make it easier to get a handle on what's going on if you had done it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Protocol Analyzer for the SQL Connection for both an error user and a working user.   Take a look at the behavior of the connections and this may point you to what is happening under the covers and perhaps where to look in your code.